# Why ChainedTransactionManager with setting timeout via annotation not working? Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, amazon-rds, transactionmanager

Application:

- Spring boot version 2.2.13.RELEASE
- postgresql version 42.2.10
- quartz version 2.3.2
- quartz-jobs version 2.3.2

I have implemented a job quartz that calls a method implemented in a @Service bean. Into this method there are interactions with two Data base (Oracle and PostgreSql). Every Db is inizialized with a Hikari Connection pool

Postgresql DB in configuration bean:

```
        @Bean(value="sreDataSource")
        public DataSource dataSource() {
        
            HikariConfig hikariConfig = new HikariConfig();
            hikariConfig.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
            hikariConfig.setJdbcUrl(datasourceUrl); 
            hikariConfig.setUsername(datasourceUsername);
            hikariConfig.setPassword(datasourcePassword);
            hikariConfig.setConnectionInitSql("set time zone 'UTC'");
            hikariConfig.setMaximumPoolSize(maxPoolSize);
            hikariConfig.setConnectionTestQuery("SELECT 1");
            hikariConfig.setPoolName("springHikariCP");
        
            return new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig);
            
        }
    /**
         * @return {@link JdbcTemplate}
         */
        @Bean(value="sreJdbcTemplate")
        public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate() {
            
            JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource());
            jdbcTemplate.setFetchSize(Integer.parseInt(fetchSize));
            jdbcTemplate.setQueryTimeout(60);
            
            return jdbcTemplate;
        }
    
        
        /**
         * Create the namedJdbcTemplate bean for the SRE database
         * @return {@link NamedParameterJdbcTemplate}
         */
        @Bean(value="sreNamedParameterJdbcTemplate")
        public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate() {
            
            return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(jdbcTemplate());
        }
        
        
        /**
         * @param dataSource
         * @return {@link PlatformTransactionManager}
         */
        @Bean(value="sreTransactionManager")
        public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(@Qualifier("sreDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
            
            return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
        }
/**
     * @param sreTransactionManager
     * @param assetTransactionManager
     * @return {@link ChainedTransactionManager}
     */
    @Bean(value="chainedTransactionManager")
    public ChainedTransactionManager transactionManager(@Qualifier("sreTransactionManager") PlatformTransactionManager sreTransactionManager,
                                                    @Qualifier("assetTransactionManager") PlatformTransactionManager assetTransactionManager) {
         return new ChainedTransactionManager(sreTransactionManager, assetTransactionManager);
    }
```

Oracle DB in configuration bean:

```
/**
     * Datasource
     * @return Datasource
     */
    @Bean(value="assetDataSource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        
        HikariConfig hikariConfig = new HikariConfig();
        hikariConfig.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
        hikariConfig.setJdbcUrl(datasourceUrl); 
        hikariConfig.setUsername(datasourceUsername);
        hikariConfig.setPassword(datasourcePassword);
        hikariConfig.addDataSourceProperty("oracle.jdbc.timezoneAsRegion", "false");
        hikariConfig.setMaximumPoolSize(maxPoolSize);
        hikariConfig.setConnectionTestQuery("SELECT 1 from dual");
        hikariConfig.setPoolName("springHikariAssetCp");
        
        
        return new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig);
    }
    
    /**
     * JDBCTemplate
     * @return JDBCTemplate
     */
    @Bean(value="assetJdbcTemplate")
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate() {
        
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource());
        jdbcTemplate.setFetchSize(Integer.parseInt(fetchSize));
        jdbcTemplate.setQueryTimeout(60);
        
        return jdbcTemplate;
    }
    
    /**
     * Create the namedJdbcTemplate bean for the RMD database
     * @return NamedParameterJdbcTemplate
     */
    @Bean(value="assetNamedParameterJdbcTemplate")
    public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate() {
        
        return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(jdbcTemplate());
    }
    
    /**
     * Create transaction manager
     * @param dataSource Datasource
     * @return transaction manager
     */
    @Bean(value="assetTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(@Qualifier("assetDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
    }
```

The service bean is called from job quartz in a cluster.The service bean is defined as the followed:

```
/**
 * @author sgalgani
 *
 */
@Service("processSreService")
@Transactional("chainedTransactionManager")
public class ProcessSreServiceImpl implements ProcessSreService {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(ProcessSreServiceImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("historianService")
    private HistorianService historianService;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("sreEvolutionService")
    private SreEvolutionService sreEvolutionService;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("assetService")
    private AssetService assetService;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("configService")
    private ConfigService configService;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("engineSupportService")
    private EngineSupportService engineSupportService;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("tagAvailabilityService")
    private TagAvailabilityService tagAvailabilityService;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("engineTransformService")
    private EngineTransformService engineTransformService;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("quarantineService")
    private QuarantineService quarantineService;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("simpleRuleEventService")
    private SimpleRuleEventService simpleRuleEventService;

    @Value("${save.oracle.temporary.results}")
    private boolean saveOracleTemporaryResults;

    @Value("${enable.save.local.db.alerts}")
    private boolean enableSaveLocalDbAlerts;
    
    @Value("${simple.rule.event.service.enable}")
    private boolean simpleRuleEventServiceEnable;

    @SuppressWarnings("javadoc")
    @Override
    @Transactional(value = "chainedTransactionManager", rollbackFor = Exception.class, timeout = 120)
    public void processSre(Sre sre, List<TagLastTimestamp> tagsLastTimestamp, Metric metrics) throws Exception {

        LOGGER.info("[processSre] for JobId : {} and lineup: {} ",sre.getId(), sre.getLineupId() );
```

After failover DB action on Amazon RDS postgresql (lost connection to DB), I would exepect a transaction timeout exception after 120 seconds, but timeout is not working, why ?

Comment: Please don't post code as images as that is totally unreadable. Just post code as code.

Comment: ok, I edit the image part

Comment: I think that the issue caused by the HikariCP's connections remain hanging during the failover action on AWS RDS instance DB PostgreSQL. However the transaction timeout does't work. This article describe the issue on AWS RDS instance and HikariCP https://www.theguardian.com/info/2019/dec/02/faster-postgresql-connection-recovery. I reserve the right to do a test to solve the issue and to give an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my issue with the set the property as written in the followed article:

[faster-postgresql-connection-recovery](https://www.theguardian.com/info/2019/dec/02/faster-postgresql-connection-recovery)

My code is added configuration HikariCP:

```
hikariConfig.addDataSourceProperty("socketTimeout", "120");
```

socketTimeout to 120 seconds, so in any case the property throws the followed exception after timeout:

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method) ~[?:?]    
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:115) ~[?:?]
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168) ~[?:?]   
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:140) ~[?:?]  
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:448) ~[?:?]   
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.bytesInCompletePacket(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:68) ~[?:?]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readApplicationRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1103) ~[?:?]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:823) ~[?:?]
at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.readMore(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:161) ~[postgresql-42.2.10.jar!/:42.2.10]
at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.ensureBytes(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:128) ~[postgresql-42.2.10.jar!/:42.2.10]
at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.ensureBytes(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:113) ~[postgresql-42.2.10.jar!/:42.2.10]
at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.read(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:73) ~[postgresql-42.2.10.jar!/:42.2.10]
at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.receiveChar(PGStream.java:370) ~[postgresql-42.2.10.jar!/:42.2.10]
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2015) ~[postgresql-42.2.10.jar!/:42.2.10]
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:311) ~[postgresql-42.2.10.jar!/:42.2.10]... 17 more
```